# Getting sum complete (without pagination) of particular columns in backpack for laravel

Tags: datatables, laravel-backpack

I followed the recommendations I found [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/1441)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function ( ) {
            return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
                if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {
                    a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
                }
                if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {
                    b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
                }
                return a + b;
            }, 0 );
        } );
        
        $("#crudTable tfoot").css("display", "table-footer-group");

        crud.table.on("draw.dt", function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            total = crud.table.rows( function ( idx, data, node ) {
                return data[11].includes('Cancelado') ? false : true;} ).data().pluck(10).sum();
            total = "$" +  total.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
            $("#crudTable tfoot tr th").html(
                "&nbsp; <br> &nbsp;"
              );
            $("#crudTable tfoot tr").children().eq(10).html(
                "Total <br>"+  total
              );
        });
});
```

And I added some modifications to get the total of the column by skipping the items that have canceled status, but I have not been able to get the total of the records but without paging. With Datatable I get the records that are being drawn, but I can't find how to intercept the ajax query or modify it to get the full total on that column including filter modifications.

Currently if in the pagination I request "show all records" obviously I get the value I need. But the requirement is that this value is displayed even if the table is visually paginated.

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve that would be to overwrite the `search()` function of the `ListOperation` (it's the table ajax endpoint).

You would need do do the full query without the pagination part to get the full data, and then pass the calculation along with the paginated response for display.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have an example of this ? Even if we setOperationSetting we can achieve this fluently ;)